# Correct way to profile a block in JVM?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I saw many posts suggesting using code similar to below to profile a method in Scala:

```
  def timer[A](block: => A): A = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val ret = block
    println(s"${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}ms")
    ret
  }
```

The rationale is to `pass-by-name` for `block`. However when I tried a code snippet I find the result is not trusty.

```
object Euler006 extends App {
  def f1(n: Int): Long = {
    val numbers = 1 to n
    def square(n: Int) = n.toLong * n
    square(numbers.sum) - numbers.map(square).sum
  }

  def f2(n: Int): Long = (n.toLong - 1) * n / 2 * (n + 1) / 3 * (3 * n + 2) / 2

  {
    val r2 = timer(f2(10000))
    val r1 = timer(f1(10000))
    println(s"$r1 $r2")
  }

  System.gc()
  System.runFinalization()

  {
    val r1 = timer(f1(10000))
    val r2 = timer(f2(10000))
    println(s"$r1 $r2")
  }

}
```

The output:

```
57ms // line 1
19ms // line 2
2500166641665000 2500166641665000
7ms  // line 4
0ms  // line 5
2500166641665000 2500166641665000
```

Obviously `f2` should take little time to execute, however line 1 outputs `57ms`. I guess perhaps it's because of the JVM initialization. OTOH, line 2 and line 4 are also different although I tried garbage collection (we cannot guarantee that since JVM has some nondeterministics, but that's all I can think of).

This example is quite trivial and I should run the results for many times to actually profile them (like the `timeit` module in Python). However I'm not sure how to write the correct timer to eliminate/mitigate the potential effects as shown in the output.

### update:

JVM initialization should be included since if I add something like `timer({})` before at the beginning, *line 1* time cost soon turned to `0ms` (indicating it costs little time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously f2 should take little time to execute,

It might take some time, but it doesn't have to take a milli-second.  Your calculation could be a fraction of a milli-second.  In fact since the result is not used, the code could be discarded.

I suggest you use `System.nanoTime()` and ensure the result is used.

> guess perhaps it's because of the JVM initialization.

The first time you call code, it has to be loaded and most likely this is what you are timing

> line 2 and line 4 are also different although I tried garbage collection

The code has loaded now.  Note: if you copied the code and run another method which did the same thing, you might get similar timings.

> I should run the results for many times to actually profile them

I would ignore the first 2 seconds of running to ensure the code has warmed up, or use a micro-benchmark framework like JMH  http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

```
static int n = 10000;

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException, IOException {
    long time = 2;
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(CalcBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .warmupIterations(6)
            .forks(1)
            .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(time))
            .timeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
}
@Benchmark
public long calc() {
    return (n - 1L) * n / 2 * (n + 1) / 3 * (3 * n + 2) / 2;
}
```

prints

```
# JMH 1.11.2 (released 164 days ago, please consider updating!)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_45, VM 25.45-b02
# VM invoker: /mnt/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java
# VM options: -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/mnt/opt/idea-IC-143.1821.5/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# Warmup: 6 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 2 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: vanilla.java.jmh.CalcBenchmark.calc

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:46
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 0.105 ops/ns
# Warmup Iteration   2: 0.156 ops/ns
# Warmup Iteration   3: 0.169 ops/ns
# Warmup Iteration   4: 0.167 ops/ns
# Warmup Iteration   5: 0.166 ops/ns
# Warmup Iteration   6: 0.165 ops/ns
Iteration   1: 0.169 ops/ns
Iteration   2: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration   3: 0.165 ops/ns
Iteration   4: 0.168 ops/ns
Iteration   5: 0.163 ops/ns
Iteration   6: 0.159 ops/ns
Iteration   7: 0.162 ops/ns
Iteration   8: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration   9: 0.169 ops/ns
Iteration  10: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration  11: 0.169 ops/ns
Iteration  12: 0.162 ops/ns
Iteration  13: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration  14: 0.167 ops/ns
Iteration  15: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration  16: 0.169 ops/ns
Iteration  17: 0.166 ops/ns
Iteration  18: 0.165 ops/ns
Iteration  19: 0.170 ops/ns
Iteration  20: 0.164 ops/ns


Result "calc":
  0.166 ±(99.9%) 0.002 ops/ns [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0.159, 0.166, 0.170), stdev = 0.003
  CI (99.9%): [0.163, 0.168] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:47

Benchmark            Mode  Cnt  Score   Error   Units
CalcBenchmark.calc  thrpt   20  0.166 ± 0.002  ops/ns
```

In short your operation, once warmed up, should take about 6 ns or 0.000006 ms

---

A simpler benchmark without JMH might look like this.  Note: I trust the JMH numbers more.

```
public class SimpleCalcBenchmark {
    static int n = 10000;
    static final AtomicLong blackHole = new AtomicLong();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException, IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            long counter = 0;
            while (System.nanoTime() - start < 2e9) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                    blackHole.lazySet(calc());
                }
                counter += 100;
            }
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            System.out.printf("Took an average of %.1f ns%n", (double) time/counter);
        }
    }

    public static long calc() {
        return (n - 1L) * n / 2 * (n + 1) / 3 * (3 * n + 2) / 2;
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took an average of 10.2 ns
Took an average of 6.7 ns
Took an average of 4.7 ns
Took an average of 4.7 ns
Took an average of 4.6 ns
```

Comment: so i have to use jmh or other frameworks to benchmark it?

Comment: @HongxuChen I would suggest using JMH, or following the other tricks I suggested.

Comment: i'm asking for a lightweight trick since https://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/ mentions the executions but didn't seems using benchmarking tools.

Comment: @HongxuChen It depends on how important it to you to get a result which is not flawed and is repeatable. You can use a warmup, ensure the result is retained and use System.nanoTime() and get a reasonable result. If the result does make sense you need to improve your testing.

Comment: i tried (1) run some dummy methods and sleep 2 seconds; (2) putting the two blocks into two functions and then run them (3) using nanotime. but for the two executions of `f1`, there is still a time difference (about 32ms vs 5ms).

Comment: @HongxuChen don't sleep for 2 seconds, you must run it repeatedly for at least 2 seconds to ensure the code has warmed up, then you must run it repeatedly for another 2 seconds and average how long each one took, your result should be in nano-seconds not milli-seconds.

Comment: firstly I kept running another irrelevant method for about 2 seonds and run these two blocks, the time cost are now 1234910ns,271894ns,224666ns,11974ns. still a bit strange.

Comment: @HongxuChen I have added a test showing a similar result with less code. The result should still be < 10 ns. You have to run the method you want to test for 2 seconds as warming up irrelevant code won't help much.

Comment: thanks so much! i followed your advice to make the piece of code run several times and the time results seem reasonable (by discarding the first round 2 second execution results). BTW, is there any general way to put the value generated by the benchmarked method to a black hole so that it cannot be optimized by the compiler (the type might not be `long`)?

Comment: @HongxuChen You can use an AtomicReference or an AtomicInteger

Comment: I'd definitely repeat to the suggestion to use JMH. You really shouldn't be trying to write your own benchmark code.

Comment: @AlBlue and even if you think you know how to write a micro-benchmark I would use JMH to validate, in short always run JMH.